# How to Split a string with a set of delimiters and find what delimiter it was? Kotlin

Tags: string, split, kotlin, calculator

So I am learning Kotlin now, and I was trying to do a calculator where if we can give expression like 4+3 or 3*5 and we will get the answer so I was trying to split that input string and then find what operator is used and what are the operands.

```
var list = str.split("+","-","*","/" )
```

so how can i get the delimiter that is used to split that string too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that `split` method doesn't have this feature. You would have to split the the string via separate `split` calls. And compare the outcome with original string. If the string wasn't split by given delimiter that outcome should be the same.

Eg. like this:

```
var str = "5+1"
var delimiters = arrayOf("+","-","*","/")
var found = "Not found"
for (delimiter in delimiters) {
    var splited = str.split(delimiter)
    if(splited[0] != str) {
        found = delimiter
        break
    }
}
println(found)
```